# Failed to create directory: project\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Tags: react-native

I am trying to integrate facebook login in react-native. 
I used this documentation [React Native FDSK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/README.md),
I am getting this error

[image]

Comment: did you try cleaning cache

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: you can refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42627342/7604342 for clean and using short cut to launch and clean using terminal

Comment: i run this code "npm run clean",but i am getting a error  "npm ERR! missing script: clean"

Comment: first you will have to add scripts inside package.json then it will work

Comment: Did you know how to fix? I got the same error

Comment: me too am faacing this problem , @BenjithMathew did you get the answer

Comment: No slution here @Benjithbinja ? If you found a solution though, please update the thread.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

When you are inside your project directory try using

```
cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Comment: In Bash you need to do `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android` (note the dot and slash in front of `gradlew`).

Comment: "The term 'gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"

Comment: any idea for windows?

Answer (score 12):

@user3499413 you are right but you forgot && between clean and cd

```
cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

Try keeping the solution folder locally (**something like D:/MyProject** ) ,Since if you keep your solution/project deeply nested within folder it may cause longer path issue.

then , try running
1. npm install 
 2. react-native run-android

probably this should resolve the issue.

Comment: doesn't make sense how android related error has something to do with `npm install` ....

Answer (score 1):

```sh
cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Comment: Please explain why does this work. Also, write your code in text mode! Thanks!

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

go to your android folder and write this folder capacitor-cordova-android-plugins

write all and its sub folders then run your command again...this fixed it for me

on Mac u can right click on the folder and click Get info, then to down and change the permissions to write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

For those who didn't know the Windows [EDIT: PowerShell, not Command Prompt] syntax:

```
cd android; ./gradlew clean
cd ..; react-native run-android
```

This worked for me.
source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10367