# react-native-nested-scroll-view: processDebugManifest FAILED

Tags: react-native

I'm using the module: react-native-sticky-parallax-header.

I follow all the steps at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sticky-parallax-header without problems:

```
yarn add react-native-sticky-parallax-header

react-native link react-native-nested-scroll-view

yarn add patch-package postinstall-postinstall

"scripts": {
+  "postinstall": "patch-package"
}
```

But when I do react-native run-android, I get:

```
info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
...............................................................................................................
Unzipping C:\Users\Diogo\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv\gradle-4.10.2-all.zip to C:\Users\Diogo\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv

Welcome to Gradle 4.10.2!
> Task :react-native-nested-scroll-view:processDebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to create directory 'C:\Users\Diogo\Documents\ProjetosMobile\newproject\node_modules\react-native-nested-scroll-view\android\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug'
> root project > Resolve dependencies of :classpath
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> IDLE
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 43s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I wear:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.8
node: v10.13.0

Comment: The error says you could run your command with `--stacktrace` or `--info` or `--debug` to get more details. Try that and edit your question with more details if it doesn't help.

Comment: @DCTID, thank you very much for responding. I was not aware of the emulator that was simply not running. So I opened the android studio and ran the emulator in AVD Manager and then: cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android, as I found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642253/failed- to-create-directory-project-android-app-build-intermediates-res-merged-d. Everything works for me now.