# Not Able to Run React Native Android App in Device using USB

Tags: node.js, react-native

Guys, I have a problem in React native Android App Debugging.When I connect my Device with my system then I got below error for Running.

Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 7.7.0 (x64) and npm.

C:>F:

F:>cd F:\Test\AwesomeProject

F:\Test\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat install
Debug...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'F:\Test\AwesomeProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : U
  >   nsupported major.minor version 52.0
- Try:
  Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 19.784 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

F:\Test\AwesomeProject>

If anyone has solution please help me to solve this error.
Thanks.

Comment: can you show index.android.js file code

Comment: okay checkout my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42627342/7604342 it might solve your proble

Comment: I suggest opening the project in Android Studio first and allow gradle to run some automated tasks. Make sure you agree on all proposed upgrades and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in Android Studio. Usually you get error: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

**SOLUTION**: Install Android SDK Tools 25.1.3 (tools)