# Error when running watchman

Tags: react-native, watchman

When I run `react-native start`, I am getting the following message

Error: A non-recoverable condition has triggered.  Watchman needs your help!
The triggering condition was at timestamp=1489123194: inotify-add-watch(/var/www/html/eventManager/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi) -> The user limit on the total number of inotify watches was reached; increase the fs.inotify.max_user_watches sysctl
All requests will continue to fail with this message until you resolve
the underlying problem.  You will find more information on fixing this at
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch

```
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/bookLister/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:207:21)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:492:12)
```

Comment: are you running in device or emulator?

Comment: Check this answer given by me it can solve your problem.

Comment: yes I am using emulator

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42627342/7604342 check this out

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
echo 256 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
echo 32768 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

> watchman shutdown-server

This one helped

Comment: Happy to hear @DamianLattenero

Comment: Thanks, it helped.

Comment: It worked for me as well. But I need to enter these commands every time I reset my computer. Is there any permanent way to do it?

Comment: @JollyRoger The answer by mad_greasemonkey here will solve the problem permanently. I tried on my computer and next time when I start computer the error doesn't occur.

Comment: Thanks for this post. It helps me but each time I reboot my system I should run these lines! What should I do for solve this for ever on my system?!

Answer (score 6):

Just run these commands in terminal:

```
echo 256 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
echo 32768 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
watchman shutdown-server
```

Other Way make **Script** in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "flow": "flow",
    "flow-stop": "flow stop",
    "watch-need-help": "echo 256 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances && echo 32768 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events && echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches && watchman shutdown-server"
  },
```

Run following command on Terminal in project directory

```
npm run watch-need-help
```

Answer (score 6):

It works for me

```
watchman watch-del-all
watchman shutdown-server
```

Here is [link](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch) which I follow.

Comment: It worked for me, but add `watchman watch-project '[my project path]'` at the end.

Answer (score 5):

Increase inotify limit to increase the limit on the number of files you can monitor.

```
$ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Please go through [this](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers) for more info

Answer (score 3):

This One is Also Helpfull .

```
echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches  && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a  /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events && echo 999999 | sudo tee  -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances && watchman  shutdown-server
```

Answer (score 1):

updating

> watchman

to latest(4.7.0) version helped me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

this one helped found it on github issues

```
echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances && watchman shutdown-server && sudo sysctl -p
```

https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/163 by @eladcandroid [1]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by trying one of the below solutions:

first pass hit line of code in your terminal and test it :

```
echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches  && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a  /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events && echo 999999 | sudo tee  -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances && watchman  shutdown-server
```

or try to use "react-native run-android"  or "run-ios" in the root of your project and then (in other terminal) "react-native start"

otherwise perhaps the debugger page was left open from previous sessions. Closing the tab completely and then opening the debugger in a new tab solved the issue.

if none of the above solution doesn't work with you try to restart your PC

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem even after reinstalling watchman using homebrew: after deleting the pid, log and sock files, the following steps worked for me:

- touch pid && touch log && touch sock
- watchman --foreground --logfile=/dev/stdout
- Allowed accessibility permissions : sudo chmod 700 /usr/local
  -closed all terminals and re-runned my commands.
  That should help.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances && watchman shutdown-server && sudo sysctl -p
```

This command should resolve this error.