# react-native start process killed

Tags: react-native, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS . For react-native all setup are done(installed watchman) , but still while i am running the react-native start command , it take 100% cpu utilization and after some 2-3 minute the process got killed and then the cpu utilization got normal .

Every time while i run react-native start command for the 1st time . It showing some watchman error and then i follow this link [Error when running watchman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711008/error-when-running-watchman).

After that  while running the command again it agin take 100% cpu utilization and process got killed